# error: cannot find symbol class GlideBitmapDrawable

Tags: android, android-glide

Hi am getting the error: cannot find symbol class GlideBitmapDrawable ,when i try to compile a project in android studio . How to resolve the error.

I have added these three dependencies in module:app

```
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.0.0-RC1"
```

Am getting here in import statement and code at GlideBitmapDrawable

```
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.GlideBitmapDrawable;
 try {
            GlideBitmapDrawable drawable = (GlideBitmapDrawable) photoView.getDrawable();
            bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
        }
```

Can any one please suggest what am missing in this?

Comment: Read [Glide Drawables](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/migrating.html#drawables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
BitmapDrawable.
```

Instead of

```
GlideBitmapDrawable
```

From docs of glide

> `GlideDrawable` in Glide v3 has been removed in favor of the standard Android `Drawable`. **`GlideBitmapDrawable` has been removed in favor of `BitmapDrawable`.**

for more information please read Read [Glide Drawables](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/migrating.html#drawables)

Answer (score 0):

`GlideBitmapDrawable` is from Glide 3, you are now using Glide 4 which changes a lot in their architecture. Check this out 
https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/migrating.html